# Databricks SQL throws PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER

Tags: sql, datetime, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a column in my databricks table, with a customised date time format as string,
while trying to convert the string to datetime I am observing below error
`PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER`

SQL Command

> select to_date(ORDERDATE, 'M/dd/yyyy H:mm') from sales_kaggle_chart limit 10;

The format of ORDERDATE column is `M/dd/yyyy H:mm`

example of ORDERDATE columns `10/10/2003 0:00` and `8/25/2003 0:00`

complete error message

> Job aborted due to stage failure: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
> Fail to parse '5/7/2003' in the new parser. You can set "legacy_time_parser_policy" to "LEGACY" to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to "CORRECTED" and treat it as an invalid datetime string.

Note: the same command works for a single value

> SELECT to_date("12/24/2003 0:00", 'M/d/yyyy H:mm') as date;

Comment: You should try with 'M/d/yyyy H:mm' and it should work. It would throw an error even if any of the date value us less than 10 and you represent it without 0 prefix if you use dd in the format.

Comment: Thanks Nikunj Kakadiya, the solution worked, the part where i got confused the error message , thanks for the infro.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting to legacy parser, like the error message is hinting you?

```sql
SET legacy_time_parser_policy = legacy;
SELECT to_date(ORDERDATE, 'M/dd/yyyy H:mm') FROM sales_kaggle_chart LIMIT 10;
```

This error is quite common, and adjusting configuration typically does the job.

Comment: Thanks Nikunj Kakadiya mentioned and I have able to get the sql work.